# Delete a Dataflow Job and Maximum Number of Jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, jobs

As Data-flow jobs cannot be deleted but drained/cancelled only, there are a lot of cancelled jobs showing on my UI console.

Can I make them disappear from my console?

Also as the job cannot be deleted, is there any maximum limit of data-flow jobs a user can create after which the quota fill be full?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) you have the limit of the dataflow service (maximum of concurrent running jobs, nb of VM per job,...). You can request quota increase if you need (concurrent jobs)

About the UI, the history length is 30 days (based on Stackdriver standard log retention)

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow jobs can’t be deleted, but you can use filters to avoid seeing some jobs.

You can check the public Feature Request [1], which I’m afraid has no ETA.

Regarding limits of jobs, you can consult the quotas in Dataflow documentation [2].

[1] - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110798648

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas